# How do you calculate the size of bytes in a data structure in C, without using the sizeof() operator?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

[image]

this question has got me so confused as to how the answer is 3. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: 8 possible values ("0-", "0+", "A-", "A+", "B-", "B+", "AB-", "AB+")... so 3 bits. `2 ^ 3 == 8`

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with C, arrays or pointers or sizeof. The question is about information theory -- 2 rhesus factors = 1 bit, 'A,B,AB and O' for blood types require 2 bits.

Put it another way:

> There are 4 main blood groups (types of blood) – A, B, AB and O. Your
> blood group is determined by the genes you inherit from your parents.
> Each group can be either RhD positive or RhD negative, which means in
> total there are 8 blood groups.

log2(8) == 3

If the result would have been a fraction, say log2(7) = 2.807, the result would have been still 3 (or ceil(2.807)) for most practical purposes.